# get all facebook comments for a link shared

Tags: facebook, fb-graph

I want to get all the comments made on facebook on a particular link.
see this image: http://cl.ly/062k1T380V1V3y2b1t0G, I want to get all 55 commments for that link. Is there any way I can do it?

I have tried graph.facebook.com/search?q=madhyamam.com, but the output is not accurate, or return null value.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the url by querying all of the url's you have linked from your page:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT link_id, created_time, title, url FROM link WHERE owner = YOUR_FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

That should give you a list of your urls and their ids. With the id you should be able to get the comments to it:

https://graph.facebook.com/LINK_ID/comments

That will give you all of the info on your comments.

Comment: I wanted a solution like these `http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select%20url,%20id%20from%20object_url%20where%20url%20=%20%27cleartrip.com%27 `

Answer (score -1):

yoo can easily get mobile number of the user by this url https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN......
the output comes in json format , after that you got the string , in there is value for key ..."mobile_phone" 
 Otherwise ,,,it is also beneficial for you https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=address,mobile_phone&
access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN ...in this case you have to take permissions from the facebook api..

Thanks